# Redux can't add a prop into the state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to add prop `basket: "true"` to a product, what i pressed on. But it doesn't work.
Action:

```
    export const addToBasket = (name) => {
     return {
       type: "BASKET",
       payload: name,
     };
    }
```

reducer:

```
    import Alert from 'react-native'
export default function (state=null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "BASKET":
       var productToUpdate = state.products.find(item => item.name === action.payload);
       productToUpdate = { ...productToUpdate, basket: true }
       var products = state.products.filter(item => item.name !== productToUpdate.name);
       Alert.alert(productToUpdate)
       return { ...state, ...state.products, productToUpdate }
  
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  };
}
```

ProductDetails. Here I use my reducer in:

```
  <Text onPress={() => this.props.addToBasket.bind(this, this.props.product.name)} style={styles.name}>{this.props.product.name}</Text>:
```

Full code of ProductDetails(without import and styles):

```
ProductDetails extends Component {
    render() {
       const { navigation } = this.props;
      if (!this.props.product) {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Choose a product</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
       return (
    
         <View style={styles.productDetailsContainer}>
           <Image
              style={styles.productImg}
              source={{
                uri: this.props.product.img,
              }}
            />
            <View styles={styles.row}>
              <View>
                <Text onPress={() => this.props.addToBasket.bind(this, this.props.product.name)} style={styles.name}>{this.props.product.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.price}>{this.props.product.price}</Text>
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.flexEnd} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Basket')}>Привет!</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
       );
     }
    }
    function mapStateToProps (state) {
      return {
        product: state.active
      };
    }
    function matchDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({addToBasket: addToBasket}, dispatch)
    }
    export default connect (mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(ProductDetails);
```

Basket. Here I want to show my products with basket: "true". I do it in function named showProductsList() and I show it in View:

```
   class Basket extends Component {
    render() {
       const showProductsList = (type, maxlength) => {
         var currentLength = 0;
         return this.props.products.map ((product) => {
           if(product.basket == type & currentLength < maxlength) {
             currentLength += 1;
             return (
                    <View key={product.id}>
                 <Image
                   source={{
                     uri: product.img,
                   }}
                 />
                   <View>
                     <Text>{product.name}</Text>
                     <Text>Price: {product.price}</Text>
                   </View>
                 </View>
             );
           }
         })
    
       }
       if (!this.props.products) {
         return (
           <View>
             <Text>Выберите товар</Text>
           </View>
         );
       } else {
       return (
         <View>
          {showProductsList("true", 4)}
         </View>
       )
    }
    }
    }
    
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        products: state.products
      };
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Basket);
```

But it doesn't show anything. What i need to do?

Comment: Where's your reducer?

Comment: What do you mean? It is in action.js file. If you are about that i don't import it, i wrote above "Full code of ProductDetails(without import and styles)"

Comment: Oh, sorry, I corrected post. The propblem is urgent

Comment: Well, right now you are not returning `hmm`, which appears to be your new state. Are you getting to where `hmm` is set (i.e, your action is dispatching as expected)? Also, is your intent to remove `productToUpdate` from the `products`, and move it out to a separate part of the state tree? That seems odd.

Comment: I suspect what you actually want is something like this: `state.products.map(p => p.name === action,payload ? {...p, basket: true} : p)`, and use that to replace `products` in `state`

Comment: Hi, rfestag. I refreshed the code. Now it is without hmm, but it still don't work

Comment: This code has a lot of problems. var instead of const and let, unused variables, class based react components, formatting issues, naming issues. I think you need to study the principals of programing and read about the eco system in react before you make an app with react native and redux.